# Cannot infer type arguments for ArraySortedMap<>

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an assignment regarding generics. -jdk.13.02, Eclipse.

`Map<String, Person> personByFirstName = new ArrayMap<>();`

This line of code gives me the error: "cannot infere type arguments for ArrayMap"

this is the header of the Interface Map:

`public interface Map<K, V> extends Iterable<Map.Entry<K, V>>`

this is the class ArrayMap:

```
public class ArrayMap <K, V> implements Map<K, V>{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected Entry<K, V>[] array = (Entry<K, V>[]) new Entry[16];
    protected int nEntries = 0;

    ArrayMap(){

    }
```

... etc.
The @suppresswarnings was required as per the assignment.

Does anyone has an idea what could be going on here or is it not enough information? I am just guessing that the problem lies in the class headers/ generics.
 I tried googling the error and other things but have not found anything.

Thanks

Comment: Did you implement your own `Map` interface?

Comment: I solved the problem by 1) creating a new project with the class construct first and changing the boundaries of ArrayMap and ArraySortedMap to 
`<K extends Comparable <? super K>, V> `
(which makes sense now) and 2) copying the code of the class bodies to the new project (step 1) did not help in the old project but i dont know why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine for me:[personbyfirst name declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5atY.png)

Heres the same arraymap you have. So id guess you either implemented a method in a broken way or messed up an import. Try to make a new project with the same code.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class ArrayMap <K, V> implements Map<K, V> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected Entry<K, V>[] array = (Entry<K, V>[]) new Entry[16];
    protected int nEntries = 0;

    ArrayMap(){

    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {

    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {

    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks - creating a new project solved the mentioned error in my main class. I Still have the same error some lines down regarding a different clas ArraySortedMap which extends ArrayMap somehow.

Comment: plz click the check near my answer to mark as answered.
Id guess you are importing the classes wrong- try to use auto-import in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I have just implemented your code myself and it works for me.

However, I did see that error at first, where I had this line:

```
Map<String, Person> personByFirstName = new ArrayMap<>();
```

It's because I was importing java.util.Map. Make sure you import your own Map, instead of java.util.Map.